# OpenMP: Get total number of running threads

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I need to know the total number of threads that my application has spawned via OpenMP. Unfortunately, the `omp_get_num_threads()` function does **not** work here since it only yields the number of threads in the current team.

However, my code runs recursively (divide and conquer, basically) and I want to spawn new threads as long as there are still idle processors, but no more.

Is there a way to get around the limitations of `omp_get_num_threads` and get the *total* number of running threads?

If more detail is required, consider the following pseudo-code that models my workflow quite closely:

```
function divide_and_conquer(Job job, int total_num_threads):
  if job.is_leaf(): # Recurrence base case.
    job.process()
    return

  left, right = job.divide()

  current_num_threads = omp_get_num_threads()
  if current_num_threads < total_num_threads: # (1)
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)
      #pragma omp section
        divide_and_conquer(left, total_num_threads)
      #pragma omp section
        divide_and_conquer(right, total_num_threads)

  else:
    divide_and_conquer(left, total_num_threads)
    divide_and_conquer(right, total_num_threads)

  job = merge(left, right)
```

If I call this code with a `total_num_threads` value of 4, the conditional annotated with `(1)` will *always* evaluate to `true` (because each thread team will contain at most two threads) and thus the code will always spawn two new threads, no matter how many threads are already running at a higher level.

**I am searching for a *platform-independent* way of determining the total number of threads that are currently running in my application.**

Comment: You could set `OMP_THREAD_LIMIT` environment variable to limit the maximum number of OpenMP threads available to a program.

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: considering the function definition, I guess OP wants a dynamic limit, which can't be provided by the environment variable.

Comment: @jweyrich: I've commented on the *'I want to spawn new threads as long as there are still idle processors, but no more.'* part. The number of CPUs is not very dynamic and the environment variable will do.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Having in mind you know the exact amount of threads being created, the simplest solution I come up with is keeping your own thread counter.

Be aware I'm completely in the dark about OpenMP as I've never really used it.

Comment: Remember that he is creating threads recursively? You'd need the counter to be in shared memory and set it with a critical region. Not a good idea.

Answer (score 5):

I think there isn't any such routine in at least OpenMP 3; and if there was, I'm not sure it would help, as there's obviously a huge race condition in between the counting of the number of threads and the forking.  You could end up overshooting your target number of threads by almost a factor of 2 if everyone sees that there's room for one thread left and then everyone spawns a thread.

If this really is the structure of your program, though, and you just want to limit the total number of threads, there are options (all of these are OpenMP 3.0):

1. Use the `OMP_THREAD_LIMIT` environment variable to limit the total number of OpenMP threads
2. Use `OMP_MAX_ACTIVE_LEVELS`, or `omp_set_max_active_levels()`, or test against `omp_get_level()`, to limit how deeply nested your threads are; if you only want 16 threads, limit to 4 levels of nesting
3. If you want finer control than powers of two, you can use `omp_get_level()` to find your level, and call `omp_get_ancestor_thread_num(int level)` at various levels to find out which thread was your parent, grandparent, etc and from that (using this simple left-right forking) determine a  global thread ID.   (I think in this case it would go something like ∑<sub>l=0..L-1</sub> a<sub>l</sub> 2<sup>L-l</sup> where l is the level number starting at 0 and a is the ancestor thread number at that level).   This would let you (say) allow threads 0-3 to fork but not 4-7, so that you'd end up with 12 rather than 16 threads.   I think this only works in such a regular situation; if each parent thread forked a different number of child threads, I don't think you could determine a unique global thread ID because it looks like you can only query your direct ancestors.

Comment: (1) You are right about the race condition. It doesn’t affect correctness though and even with that race condition the performance of capping the the thread number is vastly better than not capping. (2) Your proposed approach to capping the thread number is of course vastly superior to mine. However, I cannot use it since the number of processors in my code *has* to be user controllable. I’m effectively forced to subvert OpenMP’s thread management. Not ideal, I know, but outside of my control (for the moment).

Comment: Fair enough; sometimes there are other constraints you have to work within.

Comment: your suggestion (3) actually looks incredibly good. Unfortuntely, I also have to support OpenMP 2.5. :-(

Answer (score 2):

The code you have shown has a problem in that an "omp section" has to be within the lexical scope of an "omp sections".  I am assuming that you meant the "omp parallel" to be an "omp parallel sections".  The other way to do this, is to use "omp task" and then you don't have to keep count of the number of threads.  You would just assign the threads to the parallel region and allow the OpenMP implementation to assign the tasks to the threads.

Comment: Unfortunately, OpenMP 2.5 doesn’t have tasks yet. You’re right concerning the `sections` pragma.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party...

I had a similar problem and solved it with this method (in C):

```
int get_num_threads(void) {
    int num_threads = 1;
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp single
        num_threads = omp_get_num_threads();
    }
    return num_threads;
}
```

It creates a parallel region and lets one thread save the number of threads available in this region. It might not be the fastest approach but it works fine for me.

EDIT:

Actually, I discovered that this is compiler dependent. My proposed method in fact does not work in newer Clang versions. This is my new version to still get the total number of available threads (which is even more ugly than before):

```
int get_num_threads(void) {
    int num_threads = 0;
    #pragma omp parallel reduction(+:num_threads)
    num_threads += 1;
    return num_threads;
}
```

(I found this somewhere on the internet but cannot find the site anymore)

Comment: The op stated, that `omp_get_num_threads()` yields the wrong result in his scenario.

Comment: Yes because - as OP pointed out correctly - `omp_get_num_threads()` only yields the number of threads in the current team. Since in OPs code `omp_get_num_threads()` is not called within a `#pragam omp parallel` region it will always return 1. The method above should fix this problem.