# OpenMP and nested parallelism

Tags: c++, openmp

I would like to "nest" parallel for using OpenMP. Here is a toy code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

void subproblem(int m) {
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for (int j{0}; j < m; ++j) {
    double sum{0.0};
    for (int k{0}; k < 10000000; ++k) {
      sum += std::cos(static_cast<double>(k));
    }
    #pragma omp critical
    { std::cout << "Sum: " << sum << std::endl; }
  }
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
  int n{2};
  int m{8};

  #pragma omp parallel for
  for (int i{0}; i < n; ++i) {
    subproblem(m);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Here is what I want:

- If n >= (number of cores on my machine), I want only the first loop to be parallelized.
- If n < (number of cores on my machine), I want OpenMP to launch thread in the inner loop, but I don't want the total number of threads to exceed the number of cores on my machine.

So far, I have only found a solution that disables nested parallelism or always allow it, but I am looking at a way to enable it only if the number of threads launched is below the number of cores.

Is there an OpenMP solution for that using tasks?

Answer (score 5):

Rather than using a pair of nested parallel sections, you can tell OpenMP to "collapse" the nested loops into a single parallel section over the n*m iteration space:

```
#pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)
for (int i{0}; i < n; ++i) {
  for (int j{0}; j < m; ++j) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

This will allow it to divide the work appropriately regardless of the relative values of n and m.

Comment: Thanks. But my problems was over simplified. I have edited the original question.

Answer (score 1):

`OMP_NUM_THREADS` - Specifies the default number of threads to use in parallel regions. The value of this variable shall be a comma-separated list of positive integers; the value specified the number of threads to use for the corresponding nested level. If undefined one thread per CPU is used. (from [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp/OMP_005fNUM_005fTHREADS.html))

`omp_get_max_threads` -  maximum number of threads that are available to do work (from [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp/omp_005fget_005fmax_005fthreads.html))

`omp_get_num_threads` - number of threads in the current team (from [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp/omp_005fget_005fnum_005fthreads.html))

But AFAIK there is no function to get number of all running threads ( it's what you request:

> I don't want the total number of threads to exceed the number of cores on my machine

)

Also look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706494/openmp-get-total-number-of-running-threads)

Comment: This did not work for me. Unfortunately, by querying `OMP_NUM_THREADS` with `getenv` I changed the behaviour of the environment variable. I solved it, by opening a parallel region (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/40234153/646993).

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't the `if` clause of the `parallel` construct just do it all for you?
Here is what the 4.0 OpenMP standard says on page 44:

```
The syntax of the parallel construct is as follows:

#pragma omp parallel [clause[ [, ]clause] ...] new-line structured-block

where clause is one of the following:
  if(scalar-expression)
  num_threads(integer-expression)
  default(shared | none)
  private(list)
  firstprivate(list)
  shared(list)
  copyin(list)
  reduction(redution-identifier:list)
  proc_bind(master | close | spread)
```

I didn't try, but I guess that using the if clause just the way you described your two bullet points for whether n is greater than the number of cores on your machine might just work...
Would you care to give it a try and let us know?

Answer (score 0):

Does [taskloop](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu47.html) address your unsimplified issue? The third code block from [this page](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/exploit-nested-parallelism-with-openmp-tasking-model.html) shows it in use. and below is your code updated with it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

void subproblem(int m) {
  #pragma omp taskloop
  for (int j{0}; j < m; ++j) {
    double sum{0.0};
    for (int k{0}; k < 10000000; ++k) {
      sum += std::cos(static_cast<double>(k));
    }
    #pragma omp critical
    { std::cout << "Sum: " << sum << std::endl; }
  }
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
  int n{2};
  int m{8};

  #pragma omp parallel for
  for (int i{0}; i < n; ++i) {
    subproblem(m);
  }

  return 0;
}
```