# OpenMp detecting number of threads in nested parallelism before parallel region

Tags: c, nested, openmp

How do I detect the number of threads in OpenMp before the parallel region starts? If I use nested parallelism the environment variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS` looks like `4,64`.

```
get_nested_num_threads();
#pragma omp parallel
{
// starting 4 threads
  #pragma omp parallel
  {
    // starting 64 threads for each of the 4
  }
}
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32478353/646993) leads to my implementation of querying `OMP_NUM_THREADS` with the following code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int get_nested_num_threads(){

  char delimiter[] = ",";
  char *ptr = NULL;
  char *num_threads =  NULL;
  num_threads = getenv("OMP_NUM_THREADS");
  int threads=1, nested=0;

  ptr = strtok(num_threads, delimiter);

  while ( ptr != NULL ){
    threads *= atoi(ptr);
    ptr = strtok(NULL,delimiter);
    nested += 1;
  }

  assert( nested <= 2 );
  return threads;
}
```

Unfortunately if I call `getenv("OMP_NUM_THREADS")` then I observe a nested parallelism of `4,4` instead of `4,64`. Which is really strange to me. Do you have an explanation for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it, by opening a nested parallel region to query all threads:

```
int get_nested_num_threads(){
  int threads=1;

#pragma omp parallel shared(threads)
  {
  #pragma omp single
    {
      threads = omp_get_num_threads();

      #pragma omp parallel shared(threads)
      {
        #pragma omp single
        {
          threads *= omp_get_num_threads();
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return threads;
}
```

As far as I know, you do not need to use `firstprivate` and `lastprivate` in C for this case. But you have to do it in Fortran.

Comment: If you worry about the overhead of creating and freeing resources of  parallel regions, you could set `KMP_BLOCKTIME` to a value of 200 ms on intel machines.